# Javascript function fails to perform task in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've been researching this problem for a while, and given the immense amount of issues Google Chrome seems to have with Javascript, I've been having trouble finding anyone with this same issue.

The problem is this: when the anchor calls a new function which replaces the contents of a div, it shows the proper result for a moment before reverting to the default contents of the div prior to any changes by Javascript.

Here's the script:

```
function prologueThree() {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = document.getElementById('prologue3').innerHTML;
}

function prologueFour() {
    userName = document.getElementById('yourname').value;
    if(userName.length === 0) {
        alert("Erm... are you sure that\'s your name?");
        prologueThree();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<center> \
<img src="http://pokemonroleplay.thedevhome.net/images/Gameboy/characters/red.png"><br> \
Right, so your name is ' + userName + '! \
<br><br> \
<a onclick="prologueFive()"><button>>>Continue>></button></a></center>';
    }
}
```

This is only a snippet of the script, but the entire thing works fine in Firefox and for the first three prologue functions it works fine in Chrome. It's only when it tries to run prologueFour that it freaks out and go back. I've also tried the Chrome developer console, but it never registers an error.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Chrome issues with JavaScript? Like what? This is all very vague. Try emulating your problem on jsfiddle.net and posting a link here.

Comment: Can you expend on 'freak out'? Logs errors? If so, what errors? Causes your monitor to bleed? If so, what colour?

Comment: Since the question has been migrated from the `programmers.stackexchange.com`, [this is a gift](http://jsfiddle.net/89f5J/) from the `stackoverflow.com` users. Built a fiddle for you and seems working, now describe your problem properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I went to your [site](http://pokemonroleplay.thedevhome.net)
and I noticed you are binding an `onclick` to a `submit` button in your form without preventing the default behavior from executing, the default behavior being a form submission which refreshes the page and thus makes you lose your place and go back to the beginning.  Use a plain old button or anchor tag like you do for your previous prologues.  If you insist on using a submit for whatever reason, prevent the default behavior like so:

```
function prologueFour(e) {
    typeof e.preventDefault === 'function'
        ? e.preventDefault()
        : e.returnValue = false;
    // now rest of code can continue without page refresh
}
```

Comment: That's helpful! But if I just use a button, because it's all the same page I'm assuming Javascript will retain the value of the form box I'm calling without submission?

Comment: Yes, it will.  After you evaluate the form box's contents, you can use document.getElementById('yourname').value = "", which will reset the field.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are other issues, but `>>Continue>>` isn't exactly standards-compliant html, which could be causing problems.  You should use `&gt;` instead.